# Combine and secure a dual Wordpress installation

Tags: wordpress

I've been assigned to add some features to an existing newspaper. This newspaper is based on Wordpress. They want to add a subscription feature for subscribed users to receive email with the latest news and some other stuff.

They also want a coupon system, which I'm planning to implement using CouponPress (http://www.couponpress.com/) which is a separate Wordpress installation for coupons.

They want to keep the subscribers functionality completely separated from the main blog to avoid opening security holes for attackers to gain admin or editor roles and mess with the newspaper.

What do you recommend for this?

If I keep the subscription feature attached to the second blog, is there a plugin or something to automatically email the subscriptors of the second blog with latest entries, a daily or weekly? I want the second blog to look as part of the first one for users. Maybe replicating the user list somehow in the main blog, but avoiding sign in on it.

What do you think?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Interesting question but you really should seperate them to different questions.

Answer (score 0):

just throwing an idea  for the subscription feature, if you do go the path of subscription to the other blog you can write some quick and dirty function to query the new or even an sql trigger to copy new user recordds to the other db (I don't know if mysql allows for inter db copy triggers) 
**but** - I don't really know what'll you'll achieve that way. if the data isn't secure and sanitized someone could try to run an sql injection. and then copying the record to the other db would contaminate it either.

better use on of wordpress good security plugins, harden server access etc